# SQL Server binaries compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, reference, binaries

We are currently referencing these binaries in our .NET assembly:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo 12.0.0.0
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc 12.0.0.0
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo 12.0.0.0

Version 12 of these was originally distributed with SQL Server 2014, which is also version I have currently installed on my development PC and that I test against. Our deployment server, however, has SQL Server 2016 installed (version 13.0.5153.0 exactly). I do not remember how exactly did I deploy same version 12 binaries into GAC on this server, but they are there. As a result, our solution runs fine when deployed, because correct version of binaries is found.

**How is it possible, that binaries released for SQL Server 2014 work just fine with SQL Server 2016?** Am I introducing possible issue here if I happen to use feature that has changed between (sql) server versions and the libraries I referenced will start throwing exceptions?

Comment: Because the protocol they use to talk to the server is backwards compatible

Comment: they did a surprisingly good job with backwards compatibility here. you won't be able to use API features that were introduced with 2016 recently; you will be able to use any tsql extensions in script and commands (like the beautiful DROP IF EXISTS)

Comment: Thanks. @fredrik response is basically the answer.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server installs many versions of the same assembly and exact version match is performed. Open GAC and see if assemblies are there:

[image: Many assemblies in GAC]

See also this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/working-with-assemblies-and-the-gac), especially this sentence:

> Multiple copies of assemblies with the same name but different version
>   information can be maintained in the global assembly cache.

TDS protocol used by SQL Server is also backward compatible - see [specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee320917(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: This is correct, however not an answer to the question I was asking. See fredrik's comment under my question for the answer.